# convert string of JSON to array of JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this string :

```
s = '{"segmentTime3":Tue, 29 May 2018 10:10:00 UTC +00:00, "topic":"topic11", "personRows3":[{"personI3":"Georgia", "personR3":"GS - guest"}]}, {"segmentTime3":Tue, 29 May 2018 10:15:00 UTC +00:00, "topic":"topic2", "personRows3":[{"personI3":"newPers", "personR3":"CS - correspondant"}, {"personI3":"Arkansas", "personR3":"CS - correspondant"}]}'
```

I want to convert into an array of JSON :

```
a = [
      {"segmentTime3":Tue, 29 May 2018 10:10:00 UTC +00:00, "topic":"topic11", "personRows3":[{"personI3":"Georgia", "personR3":"GS - guest"}]},    
      {"segmentTime3":Tue, 29 May 2018 10:15:00 UTC +00:00, "topic":"topic2", "personRows3":[{"personI3":"newPers", "personR3":"CS - correspondant"}, {"personI3":"Arkansas", "personR3":"CS - correspondant"}]}
    ]
```

I tried but get an array of 1 element not 2 :

```
a = JSON.parse('[' + s + ']');  // create array
a = [s];
a = [JSON.stringify(s)];
```

Comment: Your string isn't valid json. A few items are missing `"`

Comment: ok, thanks. I missed the segmentTime3 value that is missing the "

Comment: As Get Off My Lawn noted, it isn't valid JSON, but since it is a formatted date, it should be easy to get it formatted correctly with a regex. And from there you can follow the answers below.

Comment: Validate it [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**observation :**

Your `JSON String` is not having valid `JSON`.

- It should be an array of objects instead of multiple individual objects.
- Time (Tue, 29 May 2018 10: 10: 00 UTC + 00: 00) should be enclosed in `""`.

**DEMO**

```js
var s = '[{"segmentTime3":"Tue, 29 May 2018 10:10:00 UTC +00:00", "topic":"topic11", "personRows3":[{"personI3":"Georgia", "personR3":"GS - guest"}]}, {"segmentTime3":"Tue, 29 May 2018 10:15:00 UTC +00:00", "topic":"topic2", "personRows3":[{"personI3":"newPers", "personR3":"CS - correspondant"}, {"personI3":"Arkansas", "personR3":"CS - correspondant"}]}]';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(s);

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: OP's string does not start with `[`. Changing the input would change the entire problem

Comment: @Rajesh, I agree with you but that JSON string is not valid. When you will try to parse this string it will throw an error.

Comment: OP never said he has a JSON string. You can try `'[' + s + ']'`, but not sure if that will be enough if the string is not in valid format

Answer (score -1):

Can you try 
    s = '{ "elements": [' + s + '] }';

Parse it to an object and if you access "elements" key of the object, you should get the array